# How do reset a specific field in form?

Tags: angular

How to reset not the whole form, but only one field? And so that when the field is reset, it gets the value `''`, not `null`

```
 clear(): void {
    this.form.value.search = '';
    // this.form.reset();
    this.applyFilter();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the control from the form, and call `reset` on it with `''`.

```
clear(): void {
    this.form.get('value')?.reset('');
    this.applyFitler();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using HTML, what you have to do is passing an `HTMLInputElemenet`, like this:

```
clear(field: HTMLInputElement): void {
    field.value = '';
  }
```

And you will have to name your field like this:

```
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Total"
   #field
/>
```

Look the name with the `#`, it must be the same as you are passing in your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear(formControlName): void {
  this.form.patchValue({
    formControlName : ''
   })
  }
```

You can create a common function like this and pass the form-control name as a parameter of the function

Answer (score -2):

you can reset the form field using

```
this.form.get("value").reset("");
```

you can check the [reset documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset)

or you can create a general function that when you call it and pass the field name as a parameter to it, will reset the field to empty string

```
resetFieldToEmptyString(FieldName:string) {
  this.form.get(FiledName).reset("")
}
```